# Verilog : Memory block Instantiation

Tags: verilog, fpga, register-transfer-level

I used the following code to instantiate 2-D memory in a verilog

```
reg  [15:0] data_pattern_even [3:0] = {16'hFFFF,16'hFFFF,16'hFFFF,16'hFFFF};

reg  [15:0] data_pattern_ev [3:0] = {16'hFFFF,16'hFFFF,16'hFFFF,16'hFFFF};
```

This instantiation worked all right in Simulation but failed to work when actually synthesised and RTL analysis done

Can anyone elaborate to me as in how that is possible?

Comment: What is the error/warning?

Comment: No error . Just that in the RTL , all vaues of data_pattern_even arent FFFF . 1st one is FFFF and rest all are zero

Comment: FPGA or ASIC synthesis? if FPGA can you list which FPGA and tool versions your using.

Comment: artix - 7 xc7a35 and vivado 2014.2 . I heard from my friend that initialization in verilog has to be done on certain condition e.g reset . might that be the reason ?

Comment: See [UG901](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2016_2/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf) for how to describe RAMs and ROMs for Xilinx Vivado synthesis in Verilog (or VHDL).

Answer (score 3):

For Altera devices:
https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/design-examples/design-software/verilog/ver_ram.html

For Xilinx devices (as given by Paebbels):
http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2016_2/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf (Chapter 3, "Initializing RAM Contents")

For Lattice devices:
http://www.latticesemi.com/~/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/UserManuals/EI/iCEcube2_2013-08_userguide.pdf?document_id=50165 ("Initializing Inferred RAM")

For Microsemi devices:
http://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/129865-ac162-ram-initialization-and-rom-emulation-in-proasic-sup-u-plus-u-sup-devices-app-note

A short search with google and I found this:
[How to initialize contents of inferred Block RAM (BRAM) in Verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610527/how-to-initialize-contents-of-inferred-block-ram-bram-in-verilog)

Just google it :-)