# Using BRAM in verilog module

Tags: verilog

I want to use a BRAM for a model and store the output in another block of that BRAM. But when simulating, I get the following error:

```
[VRFC 10-3236] concurrent assignment to a non-net 'roundreg' is not permitted ["C:/Users/.../keccak_new2/keccak.v":58]
```

code :

```
56    reg [23:0] roundreg [1599:0];
57
58    ROUNDFUNC  RF1(.clk(clk), .in(roundreg[0]), .out(roundreg[1]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module output's can only be connected to net types in Verilog and `roundreg[1]` is not a net. If possible, you can declare `roundreg` as `wire [23:0] roundreg [1599:0]` instead, though that might affect how the rest of your code works. Note that if you can use SystemVerilog, you can avoid these complexities, and use the `logic` type instead.

You can also look at this question to see how to infer block RAM for FPGA designs:
[How to initialize contents of inferred Block RAM (BRAM) in Verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610527/how-to-initialize-contents-of-inferred-block-ram-bram-in-verilog/36613245)

Comment: Thank you for your response.I use a block RAM to reduce latency between registers. When more than two models are used, transfering data between them have a large network delay after synthesis. Is there any way to reduce this delay?